# Adding An Active Class To A Mootools Accordion Element

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, accordion, mootools

With the rise of CSS3, I'd like to control the animation used by the mootools accordion class via css transitions, and I figure the best way to do that is to assign an active class to both the toggler and element parts of the accordion.

I've been able to do that for the toggler element, but after many attempts, I can't figure out how to give the element an active class.

The mootools code I've got so far is:

```
var myAccordion = new Fx.Accordion($$('.toggler'), $$('.services-element'), {
display: 1,
fps: 24,
duration: 400,
onActive: function(toggler) { toggler.addClass('active-accordion'); },
onBackground: function(toggler) { toggler.removeClass('active-accordion'); },
show: 0,
height: false,
width: false,
opacity: 0.3,
fixedHeight: 320,
fixedWidth: null,
alwaysHide: true,
initialDisplayFx: false
});
```

If anyone can help with this, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you want to add a css class to the active services-element? Because the onActive and onBackground event functions also receive the element as a second parameter.. Not just the toggler. onActive(toggler, element), onBackground(toggler, element)

Comment: Cheers. After further playing around, I've got it, thanks to that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the info provided by Johan, I've amended the onActive and onBackground rules as follows:

```
onActive: function(toggler, element) { toggler.addClass('active-accordion'), element.addClass('active-accordion') ; },
onBackground: function(toggler, element) { toggler.removeClass('active-accordion'), element.removeClass('active-accordion'); },
```

This gives me what I need.